# Debugging Class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is the print statement in class getting executing even though i have not created any object of class -'Test'

```
class Test(object):
    print 'hi'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'in main'
```

Comment: no point putting it duplicate unless u point the link to original problem

Comment: A comprehensive answer is provided in the link that now appears over the main body of your question. Read it, it will answer your question fully.